# How to get the sum of primary table column(Eg:Price column) using foriegn key from foreign table?

Tags: sql-server

I need the sum of primary table column(Eg:Price) using foriegn key column(Eg: fk_PriceID) from foreign table

[image: data table]

Comment: dont provide example data as image. provide it as text. this looks like a simple join and sum anyway

Comment: how do you get 16,000? explain what you want in details. what's is the meaning of fk_PriceID? Is there another table called Price?

Comment: @vasya, looks like that joins onto the pk of the first table. 4000 + 2000 + 4000 + 6000 = 16000

Comment: @Vasya Price is a column name from Primary table as shown.

Comment: @ÅbďùřŔãbŽąhìď: So it's always the same as fk_ProductID. In that case, you do not need this column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select sum (tbl_equipments.Price) Price from tbl_equipments, tbl_Lead where tbl_Lead.fk_PriceId=tbl_equipments.Id

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60EZJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you keep the id of `tbl_Equipments` twice in each row of `tbl_Lead`, 
for both columns `fk_ProductsID` and `fk_PriceID`, 
so join the tables and get the sum:

```
select sum(l.Price) Price
from tbl_Lead l inner join tbl_Equipments e
on e.id = l.fk_PriceID
```